# How to clean up the session created in a WebView?

Tags: android, session, webview, android-cookiemanager

I have a `WebView` instance which allows the user to authenticate and get access to some parts of the functionality provided by the web app. Once the user has finished their work with the `WebView`, we need to clean up the session for security purposes.

What's strange, the next time I open a screen with `WebView`, the session is still alive and I can proceed where I left off, despite my attempts to clean up the session.

Things I tried to do (I actually ran the debugger to make sure these methods are called):

```
webView.clearCache(true)
webView.clearFormData()
webView.clearHistory()
webView.clearSslPreferences()
webView.clearMatches()

CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies {
    CookieManager.getInstance().flush()
}
```

The reason I'm calling `flush()` in the `removeAllCookies()`'s callback is that `removeAllCookies()` method is async, so I was thinking that maybe it takes some time to sync the state of in-memory cookies storage with persistent storage, but this does not help.

I don't do anything fancy with `CookieManager`, it's a default one provided by OS (Android 9.0 installed on Pixel 2 XL). Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Try CookieManager.getInstance().removeSessionCookie(); instead

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yup, tried this one, but to no avail - session's still up and running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, turns out the session was stored in a local storage, so all you need to do is:

```
WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()
```

Comment: Thanks, bro your answer really saved the day..!  The best way to or after clear cache we need this.